# jQuery - Calculate sum of two numbers inside one td and display inside new td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I have this code:

```
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
                <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
                <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
                <td class="random">R</td>
                <td><a href="#">12-11      </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
                <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
                <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
                <td class="random">R</td>
                <td><a href="#">22-23      </a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In the result I want to use jQuery to get a sum of numbers inside last table TD and display it into new TD. Like in the following code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
            <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
            <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
            <td class="random">R</td>
            <td><a href="#">12-11      </a></td>
            <td>[ 23 ]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
            <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
            <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
            <td class="random">R</td>
            <td><a href="#">22-23      </a></td>
            <td>[ 45 ]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Fetch `td` and get its string. Now split string using `-` and parse values to Number using `Number(string)` and perform operation. Now you have sum. Set it as `nextTD.text(sum)`

Answer (score 4):

1. use `.each()` to iterate all `tr`
2. use `.text()` to get the text
3. use `.append()` to write new `td` at last of `tr`
4. Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` or `Number()` depending on needs

```js
//iterate all tr in table 
$('.table tr').each(function() {
  // using this context to point to each tr get the last td using .last(). 
  // use .text() to get its text
  var tdval = $(this).find('td').last().text();
  
  // use split and get the first value using index 0
  var first = parseInt(tdval.split('-')[0])
  
  // use split and get the second value using index 1
  var second = parseInt(tdval.split('-')[1])
  
  // use append to append the td where you will show the sum of two number. 
  // append will put the td in last 
  $(this).append("<td>" + (first + second) + "</td>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
      <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
      <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
      <td class="random">R</td>
      <td><a href="#">12-11      </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
      <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
      <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
      <td class="random">R</td>
      <td><a href="#">22-23      </a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Explanation should be first. Also, instead of `parseInt`, use `Number`. Values can be floating as well. Though not specified

Comment: I have moved comments on previous line so that there is as minimal horizontal scroll and explanation on top so that emphasis remains on explanation and not just code.

Comment: @Rajesh fantastic mate you solved my trouble in it's best way. I hope one day I will be such an expert.

Comment: I am kind of newbie on SO, have to get used to it, @guardio, big thanks to you, brogrammer.

Comment: @Gargo glad to help mate in anyway happy coding

Answer (score 0):

1. find the last `children('td:last')` .
2. split string with `split(-)`
3. And use with [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSoZqijanUAhXMPI8KHX6cDXgQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g&sig2=kJb62QxKSBb6ytFtAkv5WA) for convert the string to number

```js
$('table tr').each(function(){
var a =$(this).children('td:last').text().trim().split('-')
$(this).append('<td>'+(parseFloat(a[0])+parseFloat(a[1]))+'</td>')
})
```

```css
table,tr,td{
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
                <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
                <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
                <td class="random">R</td>
                <td><a href="#">12-11      </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">New thing</a></td>
                <td>2017/06/04 08:00</td>
                <td><a href="#">One Thing</a><span>Another thing</span></td>
                <td class="random">R</td>
                <td><a href="#">22-23</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in this simple approach by using Vanilla JavaScript in 3 steps:

```
// 1.Get last td element from each tr element
var trsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var lastTd = [];
var tdSum = [];
var trs = Array.from(trsCollection)
trs.forEach(function(tr){
   var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
   lastTd.push(tds[tds.length-1]);
});

// 2.Calculate the sum of each last td element
lastTd.forEach(function(ltd){
   var tdNumbers = ltd.textContent.trim().split("-");
   var sum = 0;
       tdNumbers.forEach(function(num){
          sum = sum + Number(num);
       });
   tdSum.push(sum);    
});

// 3.Add new td element to each tr parent 
for (var i = 0; i < tdSum.length; i++) {
    var newTd = document.createElement("td");
    newTd.append(tdSum[i]);
    trs[i].append(newTd);
};
```

I hope this would help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=$('tr td:last-child');
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
var newElement = a[i].innerText.split('-').reduce(function(prev,curr){
return parseInt(prev) + parseInt(curr);
});

a[i].after("<td>"+newElement+"</td>");
}
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.